# PHP AJAX Login form running AJAX fail code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, authentication

I'm a little new to PHP and trying to create AJAX PHP login form, and when I run the code it console logs correct 'login good' and 'login fail' echos from PHP code, but runs the fail code in jQuery ajax code.  It does show a status 200 in Network XHR.  I've taken a look at code from past questions, and other tutorials, but don't see anything that looks different from what I've coded.  Any help resolving is very much appreciated.

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>   </form>




$(function () {    
$("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: "login.php",
      dataType: "json", // Add datatype
      data: form_data
   }).done(function (data) {
        if(data.status == "1") {
        alert("good");
        } else {
        alert("something went wrong")
        }
   }).fail(function (data) {
      console.log('fail');
      console.log(data);
   });
}); 
});


<?php
session_start();

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$msg = '';

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        echo 'login good';
        echo "<script>location.href='welcome.php'</script>";
    } else {
        $msg = 'Please enter correct username or password.';
        echo 'Login fail';
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are telling AJAX that data type is going to be JSON, but instead, you are returning a text in case of failure and success.
I fixed your code to be like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$msg = '';
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        die(json_encode(['status' => true, 'redirect' => 'welcome.php']));
    } else {
        die(json_encode(['status' => false, 'redirect' => '']));
    }
} else { ?>

    <form method="post" id="loginForm" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username"
                   autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                   autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#loginForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                var url = $(this).attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json", // Add datatype
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        if (res.status == true) {
                            window.location.href = res.redirect;
                        }else {
                            alert('error logging in');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Please note that I added the PHP code in the same HTML page

Comment: This works perfectly and helps me understand this functionality.  Thanks so much Moayad! Much appreciated!

Comment: Great @Mr.K, you can now mark my answer as the solution so it won't pop to other users as it is not solved question. Good to help :)